# How to prevent Photoshop from selecting the space after a word when double clicking it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

So when double clicking a word to select it, Photoshop likes to select the space after that word. Is there any way to prevent this? Sounds so simple, but it means having to select and drag to highlight to make an accurate selection, when it should make sense to select the word I'm double clicking.

Comment: This is especially fun when it grabs a Carriage Return character. MINDBENDINGLY frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

## No, I don't think so.

I've tried a few workarounds, but none are faster than double clicking and removing the space.

Some alternatives I tried are:

1. Place your cursor to the END of the word you want. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> to select just that word.
2. Click and drag to select the word (which you indicated).
3. Click to place your cursor at the beginning of the word, hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, then click the end of the word.

With some practice **#3** may be the best option for you. It's a lot faster than click and dragging, and more accurate than double clicking.

[image]